# Flexibly pass url parameters to from api gateway to lambda via SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

I have a simple setup where I have a lambda function subscribed to an SNS topic and I trigger it via an APIgateway method. This is how it is configured:

[image]

[image]

But when I try to send url query strings via the apigateway testing UI I get 
[image]

However, it seems I can only set up string parameters explicitly in the method request section. I want the apigateway to send via the SNS message a mapping of all the parameters to lambda.

So GET testapi?key1=value1&key2=value2

Gets sent in the message and relayed to lambda as {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'} or something like that without having to set key1 or key2 as url parameters anywhere. I have previously achieved this via the body mapping template, but how do I test via the UI if it won't let me input a url or any url parameters?

Comment: Why do want to trigger a lambda function over SNS? Api Gateway can directly trigger the Lambda function.

Comment: I need to implement asynchronous processing because my lambda function takes longer than 29s (APIgateway timeout).